# Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am trying to combine Java-config and xml-config for spring security authentication. But i received an error:

> Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed

What seems to be the problem with my code? Been googling for answers but have not found any.

Thanks in advance. hope you can help me.

Stack-trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

java-config: SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
     .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/webapp/resources/**").permitAll() 
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
     .formLogin()
         .loginPage("/login")
         .permitAll()
         .and()
     .logout()                                    
         .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void registerGlobalAuthentication(
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

i have already declared component-scanning in my servlet-context.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ph.project.p3.conf" />
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding a `@Component` annotation. That way the autowiring should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `<context:component-scan>` in Spring-config file. Otherwise your application will not scan your package structure to find and register beans within application context.

**Syntax:** `<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.<yourapplicationName>"/>`
Eg: `<context:component-scan base-package="oph.project.p3.conf"/>`

Comment: Hi @AnilSatija, thanks for the response. As i stated above in my question i have already declared component-scan on my servlet-context.xml and tried it also on my root-context.xml. i have also tried "ph.project.p3" removing the .conf but same error still occurred cannot autowire the AuthorizationConfiguration.