# AutoWired Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is the error :

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Here is my pom.xml ::

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.atithinfosoft.traveltrip</groupId>
<artifactId>TravelTrip</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>World Travel Trip</name>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <spring-security-version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
    <jackson-version>2.4.4</jackson-version>
    <postgres.driver.version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</postgres.driver.version>

    <!--<endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>-->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.allanditzel</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-csrf-token-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- servlet container provided dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                     <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                        <keystoreFile>${basedir}/other/keystore.jks</keystoreFile>
                        <keystorePass>secret</keystorePass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is Apsecurityconfig.java code ::

```
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AppSecurityConfig.class);

//User details service created and passed in security file
@Autowired
private SecurityUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter csrfTokenFilter = new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter();
    http.addFilterAfter(csrfTokenFilter, CsrfFilter.class);

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/public/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/img/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/bower_components/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(new AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()))
            .loginPage("/resources/public/login.html")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/resources/public/login.html")
            .permitAll();

    if ("true".equals(System.getProperty("httpsOnly"))) {
        LOGGER.info("launching the application in HTTPS-only mode");
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

}

Here is ServletContextConfig.java code ::

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.atithinfosoft.traveltrip.controllers")
public class ServletContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

//    @Bean
//    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
//        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
//        resolver.setPrefix("/resources/");
//        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
//        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
//        return resolver;
//    }

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
}
```

I am unable to run it. Build is created sussecfully but generate error.
as GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false

Comment: Add your spring.xml file. Also see if these questions can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526132/could-not-autowire-field-private-org-springframework-security-core-userdetails     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262168/error-creating-bean-with-name-securityconfig-injection-of-autowired-dependenc

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to enable the security configuration like this

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
//...
}
```